# Как обойти баг с запуском приложения в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, отладка

Когда я запускаю приложение **без** отладки на телефоне (физическом), то телефон ждёт отладчик, из-за чего приложение не запускается. Только с отладкой запускается.

А как **без** отладки запустить? Перезапускал студию - не помогло.

Comment: Возможно вы что-то в настройках разработчика не то включили. Попробуйте их выключить и заново включить. Ну или поискать - вдруг вы там что-то не то включили

Comment: допускаю что это какой-то может быть косяк студии, потому что последнее время у меня запуск на реальном устройстве сталкивается с таким нюансом, не постоянно, но где-то в 60% случаев) думал что это у меня только такая беда